# What is the meaning of moment in Dipole moment

Tags: polarity, dipole

Today I read about dipole moment in my standard textbook. It said something like it is the measure of charge separation, and then proceeded to the formula , ie. Delta'charge'×bond length.
But I can't intuitively imagine what exactly dipole moment is. I can't imagine whose moment is this concept talking about. Please help me with this.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48444/what-are-dipole-moments-in-a-molecule-supposed-to-act-upon

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/74683/is-dipole-moment-a-vector

Comment: and here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/116554/is-there-a-difference-between-dipole-and-dipole-moment#comment220232_116554

Answer (score 2):

Think of it as pushing on a lever - the moment depends on distance to pivot and strength of push. The moment of pushing with 1 N on a 2 m lever is the same as pushing with 2 N on a 1 m lever.